# Backbone: multiple View Models for the same model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Newbie backbone question:

Context: Building a shopping list with backbone

I have a model class called with name, description and tags (array) properties.
I would like to create two views based on this model or this model's collection.

First view will display all items like this:

```
<ul>
<li><h3>Item 1 Name</h3>
<p>Item 1 Description</p>
<p>Tag1, Tag2 ,Tag3</p>
</li>
.......
</ul>
```

Second view will display a list of tags and count of tagged items like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Tag1<span>{count of items tagged with tag1}</span></li>
<li>Tag2<span>{count of items tagged with tag2}</span></li>
<li>Tag3<span>{count of items tagged with tag3}</span></li>
</ul>
```

I built the model, collection and view to support the first view. I would like to know the right way to use the existing model (or create a new model?) to build the second view.

Thanks in advance...

existing Item model and collection (ripped from Todo.js example)

```
window.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
// Default attributes for a todo item.
defaults: function() {
return {
order: Items.nextOrder()
};
}
});


window.ItemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

model: Item,

localStorage: new Store("items"),

nextOrder: function() {
  if (!this.length) return 1;
  return this.last().get('order') + 1;
},

comparator: function(item) {
  return item.get('order');
}

});
```

UPDATE: Even though the overriding the parse() method works when displaying Tag names with item count, I was unable to refresh tag name/item count list after adding a new item. This may be due to the fact that the views are rendering from different collections. I will try extending the ItemList collection and overriding the parse() method. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paul Yoder from Backbone.js google group provided the solution.
You can view it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/backbonejs/govwodBOKF4)

Answer (score 12):

@machineghost is right on; The models are totally decoupled from the views so you can make as many views attached to the same model as you please.  You could also extend a view, if they have logic or attributes you would like to share.  When I use Backbone I often find myself extending a parent view just to override the `render` function, or to provide a different template.

#### First view

```
ShoppingCartView = Backbone.View.extend({
  model: ShoppingCart
  ...
});
```

#### Second independent view

```
CheckoutView = Backbone.View.extend({
  model: ShoppingCart
  ...
});
```

#### Second view extends first

```
CheckoutView = ShoppingCartView.extend({ 
  template: a_different_template // syntax depends on your templating framework
  ... 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. A little more context: I have modified the Todo.js with localStorage example to suit my needs. Currently, item is stored in localStorage in this format:                           {name: "Item1", description: "Item1 Desc", tags: ["Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3"]}. Therefore, fetch() call retrieves in this format. I would like to transform (map) this format to { tagName: "Tag1", tagCount: "3"}. I believe I can do that with the underscore's map method. However, I'm not clear where I should put that piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty new to Backbone.js myself, so take this answer with a grain of salt, but I think ... you just make the second view.  The whole point of de-coupling models and views is to make it so that you don't need to do anything to the models if all you want to do is do something different with your views.

So, I *think* you just need to create YourView2, tell it to use the same model as YourView1 and you should be in business.

Comment: Don't you think the second view needs its own model? It is not like I'm displaying the same model with a slightly different template. I need to get the count of items by tag name. Ideally, the second view would use a model like this: {tagName:"Tag1", tagCount: "4"}

Comment: I'm not clear on why that would require (or even encourage) making a separate model.  Can't you just add a tagCount to your existing model, and then re-use it in view #2?  Generally speaking (in any MVC paradigm), you should only need to use a new model to represent a new thing.  If you only want to represent the old thing slightly differently, you can just modify the original model (or, if you really don't want to do that for whatever reason, like maybe the original model has a million lines already, you could always subclass the original model ...).

Comment: I can't see how adding tagCount to the existing model will help. Then you would have a tagCount attribute with every item. Given a list of items I would like to display the tag name and the number of items that are tagged with that tag. Kinda like a GROUP BY clause in SQL.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood.  In that case, why not just add the functionality to your collection (ItemList)?

Comment: Because I need to display all items in one page and item count by tag name on another page.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not understanding: what does the fact that this code is used differently on two different pages have to do with ... well, with anything?  How you organize your JS should in no way  be impacted by how many pages you use that JS on (unless you're using completely different JS on one page vs. another, but if that were the case this whole question would be moot).

Comment: If I add the parse() function I explained in my answer to ItemList, the fetch will return {tagName: "Tag1", itemCount: "4"}. If I don't, fetch() will return {name: "Item1", description: "Item 1 Desc", tags: ["Tag1", "Tag2"]}. I need BOTH. Therefore, I feel I need two collection objects. One that has the parse() function to display item count by tag name view. One that does not have the parse function to display item name, item description, tags.

Answer (score 0):

After a little research, I found [Collection.Parse](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-parse) method that seems to be right place for  transforming the response after a fetch() operation. Looks like I will need a new set model, collection and view objects. This is how I implemented the parse function in my collection object. Tested successfully in Chrome. Feel free to suggest improvements

```
    <snip>
    parse: function(response) {

        var items = response; //the raw item model returned from localStorage  
        var tagNameItemCount = [];
        var selectedTags = ["Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3"];
        for(i = 0; i < selectedTags.length; i++){
            var currentTagName = selectedTags[i];
            var currentItemCount = this.getItemsCountByTagName(currentTagName, items);
            tagNameItemCount.push({tagName: currentTagName, tagCount: currentItemCount});
        }

        return tagNameItemCount;



       },
getItemsCountByTagName: function (tagName, items) {
                        var taggedItems = _.filter(items, function(item){ return _.include(item.tags, tagName); });
                        return taggedItems.length;
                       },

     </snip>
```

Comment: While creating a new view/collection and overriding parse works for display purposes, the view is not refreshed after Items collection is modified. Updated the question to reflect this issue.