# One model to many views

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

One of the advantages of MVC is its support for many views sharing the same model, however I can't find any examples of this using backbone.js. In every example I've looked at, there is a single view for each model or collection. Is the sharing of models supported? For example a gallery app where the image can be selected by next/previous buttons, thumbnails, double- clicking the image or a list of popular images. All are changing the selection of an image on an Images collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything connecting the view to the model is done by event binding, so, yes.  Many views can be bound to one model.

Comment: See here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597726/backbone-multiple-view-models-for-the-same-model